# Angular/ Node.js Website - Automatic mail notification

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, email

I want to check every 12hours, if new things are available for my users. If so, an email should be send automatically by the server.
I took a look at https://nodemailer.com, but I don't know if thats the right tool; the most important thing is, that the server e.g. at midnight runs this job automatically and sends the mails.

Can somebody give me an advice?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use nodemailer for sure, there are other mailing modules like mailgun. You just need to use one of these module to send mails. It's very easy to use. You can also use event module to fire event at midnight which will check updates and send mail.